# copy object not instantiating

Tags: java, oop, copy

I'm trying to create a copy of my Board object but it doesn't seem to be instantiating. Can someone tell me why?

```
    class Board {
       private Board _copyBoard; 
       private int _size;
       public Board (int N) {
          _size = N;
       }
       public Board (Board b) {
            this._copyBoard = b;
       }
       int size() {
            return _size;
       }
    }
```

When I do:

```
    Board b = new Board(4);
    Board x = new Board(b);
    System.out.println(x.size()); --> 0 instead of 4.
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Please post the actual code

Comment: The second constructor, which takes an instance of type `Board`, never sets the `_size` value (which doesn't have a type, by the way).

Comment: I don't see how that could generate a `NullPointerException`, it should simply print `0`...

Comment: fixed. but, does that mean I need to reset my "_size" variable in my constructor? I thought that my _copyBoard Board variable will just "copy" everything.

Answer (score 1):

Copy constructor should normally copy the *instance variables*, and if necessary some deep state -- not keep a reference to the original object.

Your getters & methods need to be able to operate on the object's own state, in it's own variables. Having some kind of dual-path structure everywhere, with `if` statements going to *either* your own variables *or* the original instance it was copied from, is poor design and very complex/ inefficient.

```
public class Board {
   protected int      size;
   protected Cell[][] grid;
   public Board (int N) {
      this.size = N;
      // for example, create a 2D array.
      this.grid = new Cell[size][size];
   }
   public Board (Board orig) {
       this.size = orig.size();
       // deep-copy the grid.
       this.grid = new Cell[size][];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          grid[i] = Arrays.copyOf( orig.grid[i], size);
      }
   }
   public int size() {return size;}
}
```

I strongly prefer `protected` over private, for greater versatility & engineering access.

Neither do I use field prefixes, but instead disambiguate *field assignments* (in setters or other methods) with `this.`. This approach works very well for simple fields.

For collections, I suffix my fieldnames with List or Map or whatever;  parameters are named without the suffix. This makes plural operations & method-calls with pluralities clear. For example, `add (List<Customer> customers)` will add those to a field `customerList`.

Comment: Add an example and win a teddy ;)

Comment: By doing this, wouldn't I modify my original Board object if I say reset the size of my copy Board object?

Comment: No, the point is to copy internal data so that we have _separate instance & fields_ with logically the _same values_, but independently modifiable. If they weren't independent, it wouldn't be much of a copy & indeed there would be no point in it being a separate instance at all.

Comment: oh, so for arrays, I need to use arrays.copyOf() to copy an array? Meaning, I can't just set this.grid = orig.grid?

Comment: Yes, if you want those arrays to be independent copies, you have to copy them. Otherwise both Board objects will reference the same array data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Board b = new Board(4);
```

This will create a new board where its field `_size = 4`.

```
Board x = new Board(b);
```

This will create a new board where its field `_copyBoard = b`.

```
System.out.println(x.size());
```

This will print out the field `_size` of the second board. Nowhere have you linked to the `_size` variable of the first board.

You can solve this by doing

```
    public Board (Board b) {
     this._copyBoard = b;
    }

    int size() {
     if(_copyBoard != null) { 
       return _copyBoard.size(); 
     } else { 
       return _size; 
     }
    }
```

All things considered, you're probably looking at an actual copy of the data instead these classes as fields with lots of if statements.

```
class Board {
    private int _size;
    public Board (int N) {
       _size = N;
    }
    public Board (Board b) {
        _size = b.size();
    }
    int size() {
        return _size;
    }
}
```

Comment: That new version of `size()` will fail on objects constructed with the first constructor.

Comment: @David: it will, but as far as the code given and intent shown, only the current solution is within the given boundaries. I don't know his exact requirements to give a more accurate solution, but it will work for his shown testcase.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: it doesn't, I'm guessing OP mixed something up.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 Board b = new Board(4);
 Board x = new Board(b);
System.out.println(x._size); 

class Board {
    public Board _copyBoard; 
    public int _size;
    public Board (int N) {
       this._size = N;
    }
    public Board (Board b) {
         this._size = b._size;
    }
    int size() {
         return _size;
    }
 }
```

In you code you are not copying the value of size to x, Instead size is getting copied to the instance variable inside X

If you make the variable public, in your code then the below line will print the copied value in your code

```
System.out.println(x._copyBoard._size);
```